# Why aren't there solutions for electronic itemized receipt for retail in-store purchases?

Tags: credit-card, online-tools, receipt, spending

This is a personal finance question related to retail shopping. I am wondering why, with the evolution of the Web and relatively well-established credit card payment system, there is still no widely implemented solution for being able to get an electronic copy of itemized receipt of in-store purchases? (e.g. an electronic copy of your grocery receipt that lists every item purchased and its price).

The data is certainly available and probably retained in the corporate databases and extensively used for consumer analytics, sales forecasting, marketing, etc.

The email information is often also available to the retailer through the use of club/reward cards, since when you sign up for those you typically input email address. Alternatively, the retailer can transmit the itemized sale information to the credit card company, linked to the total transaction amount on the credit card activity statement (I am thinking a drop-down menu that expands to reveal itemized detail of the purchase when viewing the online credit statement).

In any case, it seems **we have the data and we have the technology.** So it's not that.

There is probably also real value in delivering such information to the customer. It would save forests by reducing the need for all those mile-long printed receipts (paper vs. electronic receipt can be a voluntary opt-in/opt-out option at checkout, just like paper or plastic).

It also solves the issue of not having the paper receipt when you need it later (say, if you buy a small appliance in a brick-and-mortar store, but don't keep the receipt which is later needed for warranty service/replacement of the product).

**Then what is preventing this service from being offered?** If you are in the corporate retail/marketing/banking business and have a good educated guess/insight, your answer would be especially appreciated but anyone is welcome to weigh in thoughts. Thank you.

Comment: This is going to be entirely opinion based.

Comment: Apple uses it in their stores, so your premise is incorrect. Personally I have no intention of giving random retailers any of my e-mail addresses, any more than I was willing to give Radio Shack my snail-mail address.

Comment: As with many things, I think the answer is "Companies are not generally interested in helping consumers unless doing so makes more money for the company, and companies don't think the benefits *to them* of doing this will outweigh the costs."

Comment: I would suggest limited demand from the consumer.  Some stores do it - Home Depot offers it, but it's just an extra choice.  Besides, one function (and perhaps the primary one) of the paper receipts is to keep customers from just walking out of the store with unpaid-for goods.

Comment: "Besides, one function (and perhaps the primary one) of the paper receipts is to keep customers from just walking out of the store with unpaid-for goods." - unless you have a phone on which you can pull it up, just like boarding pass at the airport ;)

Comment: I don't understand the question since it includes it's own answer: at some stores you can sign up for the club or otherwise give them your email.  That's a solution to the query in the title.  If you are interested in the reason a specific store doesn't offer this service, you should ask them.  By asking you demonstrate consumer interest in this.

Comment: @user662852, apologies if it's confusing, the key word is "itemized" - every item that you bought listed in electronic receipt form. email is used a lot for coupons/promotions etc, but not for providing copies of itemized receipts of in-store purchases (except for special cases as have been mentioned, e.g. Apple Pay, although I am not sure it's itemized in that case also, e.g. if I buy a bag of groceries at Whole Foods do I get a receipt listing each item I purchased?) in any case, such practice still seems very ad-hoc. I am definitely interested, though, and could be willing to pilot test it.

Comment: I have asked my mattress retailer for my itemized receipt by email years later (for a warranty issue).  The question (may?) assert retail stores already submit this data to credit card co's and the credit processor wants to be a clearinghouse for this - I challenge this assumption :)  I'm still unclear what the problem is: Are you trying to eliminate paper in society or accelerate recordkeeping for your own accounting needs?  There can be some venn overlap in poor solutions to these but i gotta say, the best solutions to these problems are in my mind different.

Comment: "for your own accounting needs" - that's it for now, I have no illusions around paper...after all tress should grow for a reason...

Comment: While you might want this, ultimately most shoppers don't care.  If you focus on your problem        specifically, there are solutions: the Chase Ink card, http://www.komando.com/tips/12292/best-apps-to-help-keep-track-of-receipts/all

Comment: Just got a notification that this question has 1000+ views, woo hoo! Not bad for a *closed* question...pssst moderators? ;)

Answer (score 3):

In some stores that is done. When I shop at the Apple store or at the Farmers market the receipt is automatically sent to my email address.

Why don't others do it?

If the target of the itemized receipt is a credit card company they would be sending data that they spent collecting to another corporation. The grocery store is collecting your data so they can sell it to their vendors. They sell to vendors the info that Gen X shoppers that buy cat food are more likely to use brand X laundry detergent then Millennials. The credit card companies could gather even more Meta data that they could sell.

Privacy. Some people don't join the reward program at the store because they don't want a company to know exactly what they buy. Even fewer would want the credit card company to have that information.

The credit card companies would have to want this level of data that would have to be stored, maintained, and protected.

Comment: Good points, including some that I had not suspected. It seems that as Apple Pay and similar competitor systems gain momentum, such functionality would become more feasible since as you say it already generates an email receipt, so it would be a matter of including an itemized list into the receipt rather than just the total. I am however still surprised this hasn't been scaled up already. Many of the reasons you cite make sense, but similar arguments could be made 20-30 years ago against reward programs or credit cards, yet here we are. So might be a matter of gradual dev-t of paymnt systems.

Comment: Even if one does not join the rewards program, payment by credit card _does_ provide the grocer a link to the payer. I have noticed that my grocer (large corporation) does track my spending via credit card number because the coupons I get (in the US Mail) differ from the coupons that my friend gets (he too is not a member of the store's rewards program but does use the same credit card to buy groceries all the time).